# How to delete lines containing specific values from a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am doing some numerical computations and a few iterations return values that are obviously incorrect (some numerical integration problem, I suppose.). I have managed to set these values to zero but this does not goes well with the ListLinePlot I'm making. So, given this context, my problem is the following:

I have a nX2 matrix where n is a fairly large number. A few elements in column 2 are zero and I want to delete them. If there was only one zero element I would identify the position j of the zero and use Delete[matrix,j]. Since I have more than one of these I've been using

```
For[j = 1, j <= Length[matrix], j = j + 1, 
If[matrix[[j, 2]] == 0, matrix = Delete[matrix, j]]
]
```

The problem is that this routine only deletes the few first lines with zeros and then stop doing that. I imagine it has something to do with Length[matrix] being changed, but I'm not sure. Could ou help me, please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried `Select`? `Select[matrix, #[[2]] != 0 &]`

Comment: ...or `Cases[]`?

Comment: ... or `DeleteCases[mat, {_, 0}]` or `Pick[mat, Unitize[mat[[;; , 2]]], 1]`?

Comment: Thank you so much. Select worked like a charm. Could you help me, though, to understand the syntax? What are the roles of # and &? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gabu Take a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica) post. The `#&` is slot/pure function notation. A slot is unnamed argument.

Comment: To learn about `#` and `&` look up [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) in the documentation.